# How to install Kafka on hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I want to install the latest release of Kafka on our HortonWorks Hadoop cluster that contains 2 master nodes, 2 edge nodes and 8 data nodes. The plan is to install Kafka on 2 out of 8 data node boxes.
Kafka will need to handle up to few million events a day an probably few batch copies of files of a size of 0.5Gb-1.2Gb.

Questions: any special configuration to data nodes or to kafka I need to consider in order to avoid a potential performance deterioration of kafka (or data nodes)?

How Kafka is normally deployed (on dedicated boxes or is it ok to run it on data nodes)?

Answer (score 0):

You can install kafka via Ambari.
Go to Homepage of Ambari -> Click on Action (Left bottom) -> Click "Add Service" -> Choose "Kafka" -> Select Nodes -> Deploy -> You are done. you have kafka on your cluster

You can see screenshots here in "Appendix A" http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/simulating-transporting-realtime-events-stream-apache-kafka/

Comment: It does not answer the question. It wasn't about about the technical way to install kafka, but about the best cluster topology in a hadoop/kafka shared cluster.

Comment: @Arnaud - question was not clear. if you talk about the best topology for kafka cluster (in produciton) - it is best to have dedicated hardware for kafka so that it do not take resources of datanodes/cotainers and affect cluster production jobs. It is very easy to scale-up/down o dedicated hardware .you can increase or tear down kafka nodes depending on load at any point of time . Hope this helps